# Why the drop-down list is sticking to top and bottom when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, dropdown

After opening drop-down, while scrolling the list is sticking on top or bottom of the div. I tried changing positions of parent div and drop list. But couldn't figure it out. Is there any way to make drop-list it scroll along with the button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="card"> 
  <div class="dropdown mb-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown mb-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown mb-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown mb-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.card {
    height: 150px;
    width: 30%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the menu gets out of boundaries, the js of bootstrap makes it stick to the boundaries to keep the menu stay by adjusting the position.

When it gets out of boundaries, bootstarp put `x-out-of-boundaries` attribute to recognize it.

You can use this to achieve it.

```
.dropdown-menu[x-out-of-boundaries] {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 30px, 0px) !important;
}
```

You can adjust the position as you want.

[Here](https://codepen.io/guswnsxodlf/pen/QWqZzmZ) is an example.